# How do you check to see if an index exists in a list, and use a default value if it does not?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have declared the following dictionary in my Python script:

```
    my_dictionary = {'course': row[0],
                'vars': [
                         {'name': 'FIRST_NAME', 'content': row[1]},
                         {'name': 'COURSE_NAME', 'content': row[2]},
                         {'name': 'HOLE_COUNT', 'content': row[3]},
                         {'name': 'SHORTNAME', 'content': row[4]},
                         {'name': 'SSS', 'content': (5 in row: row[5])},
                         {'name': 'COURSE_RECORD', 'content': (6 in row: row[6])},
                        ]
               }
```

I am wrestling with the syntax where I am trying to check if a list item exists or not:

```
                         {'name': 'SSS', 'content': (5 in row: row[5])},
                         {'name': 'COURSE_RECORD', 'content': (6 in row: row[6])},
```

Can this check be done at this point?

My syntax is incorrect because I get the following error:
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: If you want the value to evaluate to a boolean you can just use `5 in row[5]`.

Comment: @CDJB Thanks for your comment. What I am looking for is "if this is set in the array then use it".

Comment: What is `row` - a list or another dictionary? If if it is a dictionary, then `5 in row` checks if `row` contains the key `5`, however it is a list, `5 in row` will tell you if `row` contains an element with **value** `5`,

Comment: @Błotosmętek Thanks for the comment. `row` is a list. `5 in row` would return a boolean, right?

Comment: You want to see if the value of 5 exists in the list, or you want to see if the list has a fifth item?

Comment: You want the `content` to store `bool` values ?

Comment: @KenKinder I want to know if there is a fifth item in the list and if there is then use it as the value of "content"

Comment: In this case you should use `len(row)>5`

Comment: Also, what if `row[5]` does **not** exists? Should `content` be associated with `None`, '' (empty string), or not present at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
my_dictionary = {'course': row[0],
                'vars': [
                         {'name': 'FIRST_NAME', 'content': row[1]},
                         {'name': 'COURSE_NAME', 'content': row[2]},
                         {'name': 'HOLE_COUNT', 'content': row[3]},
                         {'name': 'SHORTNAME', 'content': row[4]},
                         {'name': 'SSS', 'content': (row[5] if len(row)>5 else "")},
                         {'name': 'COURSE_RECORD', 'content': (row[6] if len(row)>6 else "")},
                        ]
               }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you see if there's a fifth item in a list. This is from the interactive console (python).

Starting with a list, I can see how many elements it has:

```
>>> my_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']
>>> len(my_list)
7
```

It has seven elements. If I try to get the eighth item (remember indicies start from zero), I'll get an error:

```
>>> my_list[0]    # Looks good
'a'
>>> my_list[8]    # oh no, the eight item doesn't exist
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

So the simplest approach might be always trying to get an item by its index, then catching that error. But that's not very efficient. A simpler approach, if you have a default, would be this:

```
>>> my_list[6] if len(my_list) > 6 else 'my_default'
'g'
>>> my_list[7] if len(my_list) > 7 else 'my_default'
'my_default'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

this would have been easier in python 3 (you should remember python2 has reached eol)

This works on my end

```
my_dict={'test': ((row[5],'')[len(row)>5])}
```